# XPath to get URL and name pattern

Tags: xpath, scrapy

My goal is to get the following result(s).

```
{
    "event_name": "I’M YOUR DJ New Year Edition / 5th Anniversary Celebration",
    "url": "https://latindancecalendar.com/festivals/im-your-dj-new-year-edition-5th-anniversary-celebration-2019/"
}
```

Currently, I have the following XPath:

```
class LatindancecalendarSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "latindancecalendar"
    allowed_domains = ["latindancecalendar.com"]
    start_urls = ["https://latindancecalendar.com/festivals/location/europe/"]

    def parse(self, response):
        events = response.xpath("//div[@class='vevent']")
        for event in events:
            name = event.xpath("//a[@class='url' and @class='summary']/text()").get()
            yield {"event_name": name}
```

Html code

```
<div class="vevent">[...]</div>
<div class="vevent">[...]</div>
<div class="vevent">
   <span class="dtstart"><span class="value-title" title="2019-12-27"></span></span>
   <div style="padding-bottom: 10px;border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;margin-bottom: 10px;">
      <table class="event_table" style="line-height:normal;">
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td class="event_cell event_image"><span class="imagelabel"><a href="https://latindancecalendar.com/festivals/im-your-dj-new-year-edition-5th-anniversary-celebration-2019/"><img alt="I’M YOUR DJ New Year Edition / 5th Anniversary Celebration" class="photo" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/latindancecalendar/image/fetch/w_100,h_100/https%3A%2F%2Fi1.wp.com%2Flatindancecalendar.com%2Fdancecal%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F50015933_2182298412088647_1361353647551676416_o.jpg%3Fresize%3D350%252C350%26ssl%3D1" width="50" height="50" scale="0" style="display: block;"></a></span></td>
               <td> <span class="_5x8v _5a5j _5a5i" style="width: 50px;display: block;"> <span class="_5a4-" style="color: #fa3e3e;display: block;overflow: hidden;position: relative;text-align: center;white-space: nowrap;">DEC</span><span class="_5a4z" style="display: block;overflow: hidden;position: relative;text-align: center;white-space: nowrap;">27</span></span></td>
               <td class="event_cell event_description" style="padding: 0;">
                  <div class="eventline event_details" style="padding: 0;line-height: 14px;padding-bottom: 2px;"> <a href="https://latindancecalendar.com/festivals/im-your-dj-new-year-edition-5th-anniversary-celebration-2019/" class="url summary" style="font-size: 14px;">I’M YOUR DJ New Year Edition / 5th Anniversary Celebration</a></div>
                  <div class="addressline" style="display:none;"><span class="location">Château Lafitte Yvrac ( Bordeaux ) - SCEA Chateau LAFITTE 41 Chemin du Loup, 33370 Yvrac, Aquitaine, France</span></div>
                  <div>France</div>
                  <div class="eventpostviews" style="padding-top: 4px;"><a href="https://maps.google.com/?q=Ch%C3%A2teau+Lafitte+Yvrac+%28+Bordeaux+%29+-+SCEA+Chateau+LAFITTE+41+Chemin+du+Loup%2C+33370+Yvrac%2C+Aquitaine%2C+France" class="map_link" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt" style="padding-right: 5px;"></i>Map</a> | 34793 Seen | <a style="color:#8F8F8F;" href="https://latindancecalendar.com/report-a-listing/?listing-url=https%3A%2F%2Flatindancecalendar.com%2Ffestivals%2Fim-your-dj-new-year-edition-5th-anniversary-celebration-2019%2F" rel="nofollow"><i class="fas fa-times" style="padding-right: 3px;font-size: 11px;"></i>Report Problem</a></div>
               </td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="vevent">[...]</div>
<div class="vevent">[...]</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XPathes for `URL` and `event_name` would be:

```py
for event in events:
    yield {
        'event_name': event.xpath('.//a[@class= "url summary"]/text()').get(),
        'url': event.xpath('.//a[@class= "url summary"]/@href').get()
    }
```

You can use `.` to continue from current node which is `event` here.